# How does the new trait system work?

Tags: guild-wars-2

So the new April feature pack is live and has made some changes to the trait system as well as introducing new traits.

I logged into my lv31 Thief who has 20 trait points to find that all my traits had been reset and I had 1 available trait point.

How have the changes to the trait system led to my losing 15 trait points?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the wiki,

> Each level 80 character now has a total of 14 trait points, each
>   equivalent to 5 trait points prior to the update.
>   Characters earn 1 trait point every 6 levels starting at level 30, and two trait points
>   every 6 levels starting at level 66.

So it seems that my trait points have been adjusted to match this new system. Because I am lv31 I have only earnt 1 trait point and will need to level up to lv48 before I can get the same number of traits as I had before.

```
Level    Points earned   Total points
30          1               1  
36          1               2  
42          1               3  
48          1               4  
54          1               5  
60          1               6  
66          2               8  
72          2               10  
78          2               12  
80          2               14
```

Comment: That seems pretty silly. Why they didn't just give out one every 5 levels starting at 15? The vagaries of developers.

Comment: I agree @Affine, it's taken away the feeling of progression you got from levelling up.

Comment: I assume it's because old players leveling up new characters can use one of those scrolls that levels you up to 20. New players however...

Comment: @DavidYell I agree so much, I can't even describe it. I love to create new characters and now up to level 30 I have no feeling of progressing. Okay, I unlock weapon skills, but this is done in 5 minutes. After that, from 1 - 30 my character stays the same. Armor drops so rarely that I had to buy new armor every 5 levels from the trading post. The new trait system is the worst decision ArenaNet has made so far.